The definition of the Lie Derivative
I am aware that an answer to an almost identical question already exist, however, I found the already existing answer not helpful (at least to my current question).
Carroll defines, in his book, the Lie Derivative of a tensor field $T^{\mu}\,_{\nu}$ as
$$\mathcal{L}T^{\mu}\,_{\nu} = \lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\phi_t^* \left[ T^{\mu}\,_{\nu} (\phi_t(p) )\right]-T^{\mu}\,_{\nu}(p)}{t}.$$
And he describes the $\phi_t^* \left[ T^{\mu}\,_{\nu} (\phi_t(p) )\right]$ part as "$T^{\mu}\,_{\nu}(x)$'s value at the point $\phi_t(p)$ pulled back to $p$." And this part specifically does not make any sense to me. In previous pages he has developed the machinery of pulling back (pushing forward) various kinds of things and expressing the components of the pulled back (pushed forward) tensors in terms of the components of the old one, however he has never talked about such a thing as first calculating the components of a tensor at a point (which is a number) and pulling back that number.
After giving it some thought, I suspect what he means by this could be the following: First calculate the components at the point $\phi(p)$ and then use them to contruct a tensor at $p$ (use these components in the basis expansion).
Regardless of whether my conclusion is correct or not I want to make sense of this pulling back the number business I've described above. I would highly appreciate any help on this.

No, you first compute the pullback of the tensor field, then extract the $\mu,\nu$ component. This sort of order-of-operations confusion persists all throughout physics expositions (e.g Lagrangian mechanics, where one ought to perform derivatives then plug in the curve, or when talking about index notation regarding covariant derivatives (i.e $\nabla_aX_b$ means find $\nabla X$ first then extract the $(a,b)$ component) etc). Tbh I don’t see why Carroll even bothers introducing components here,  we can just say $(\mathcal{L}XT)(p)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|{t=0}\left[((\phi_t)^*T)(p)\right]$.

Maybe your confusion is about the use of the abstract index notation?

@peek-a-boo Thank you for your answer! I think you have a point, defining the Lie Derivative in the way you've suggested we may extract the components by just evaluating the tensor at appropriate basis vectors and if I am not mistaken it comes out to be the expression given by Carroll (assuming we abuse notation and denote the components of the pullback as the pullback of the components). I guess jumping straight into the componets does confuse me. Can you inform me on whether my conclusion are correct or not?

Yes, like I said, we always do the tensor operations first and only at the very end extract components.

It's just because you want to compare two objects at the same point. In differential geometry you can NOT compare objects at different points since they live in different spaces. The pull back allows you to bring back your tensor $T^{\mu\nu}(\phi_{t}(p))$ at the point p, there is nothing really mysterious

I am not sure if you've read my question but $T^{\mu},_{\nu} (\phi_t(p))$ is not a tensor: it is a number, namely the $\mu \nu$-th component of $T$. How are we gonna pull back a number?

Obviously if you want to do the things rigorously you should learn differential geometry not reading Carroll's book... it's meant for physicist. Take a look for instance at the Lee's book "introduction to smooth manifold". I wanted to give you the simple idea

I have the basic idea and I did not ask for what the basic idea was and just because the book is a physics book doesn't mean athours could do whatever they wish (and in fact they don't). What I am asking for here is clear: I've deteced (or at least think that I have) an inconsistency and want to figure out what's going on, the confusion is not arising from the lack of rigor, it is possibly something way worse.
